What software is available for procedurally generating translation tables for students?
I am asking a question about natural language procession (NLP)
For better or worse, the data science stack exchange (SE) seems to be where questions about natural language processing go.

Suppose that we wanted a table, like the following, for teaching kids and/or adults Spanish.




SPANISH
pod-emos
tra-bajar
en
conversación
,
vocabulario
,
gramática
o
lo que prefier-as
.




SPANGLISH
power-we
trawl-below
in
conversation
,
vocabulary
,
grammar
or
it that prefer-you
.


ENGLISH
we can
work
in
conversation
,
vocabulary
,
grammar
or
whatever you prefer
.




You can assume that I already have a dictionary where the inputs are strings of Spanish text and the output are strings of English text.
# Small Sample (or Example) of dictionary

toSpanglish = {
  "trabjar"      : "trawl below",
  "podemos"      : "power we",
  "ano"          : "annual"
  "año"          : "annual"
  "conversación" : "conversation"
}


What tool might we use to procedurally generate stack exchange mark-down tables or HTML tables?
The input will be a string of Spanish text. The output will be a string for an HTML table or stack exchange mark-down language table, a tele-type ASSCII art table, or somthing like that.
Below, we have two different examples of what the desired output might be...
| SPANISH   | pod-emos | tra-bajar   | en | conversación | , | vocabulario | , | gramática | o  | lo que prefier-as   | . |
|-----------|----------|-------------|----|--------------|---|-------------|---|-----------|----|---------------------|---|
| SPANGLISH | power-we | trawl-below | in | conversation | , | vocabulary  | , | grammar   | or | it that prefer-you  | . |
| ENGLISH   | we can   | work        | in | conversation | , | vocabulary  | , | grammar   | or | whatever you prefer | . |

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
   <th>SPANISH       </th>
   <th>pod-emos      </th>
   <th>tra-bajar     </th>
   <th>en            </th>
   <th>conversación  </th>
   <th>,             </th>
   <th>vocabulario   </th>
   <th>,             </th>
   <th> gramática    </th>
   <th> o            </th>
   <th> lo que prefier-as   </th>
   <th> .            </th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td> SPANGLISH </td><td> power-we </td><td> trawl-below </td><td> in </td><td> conversation </td><td> , </td><td> vocabulary  </td><td> , </td><td> grammar   </td><td> or </td><td> it that prefer-you  </td><td> . </td><td>
</tr> 
    <tr>
        <td> ENGLISH             </td>
        <td> we can              </td>
        <td> work                </td>
        <td> in                  </td>
        <td> conversation        </td>
        <td>,                    </td>
        <td> vocabulary          </td>
        <td> ,                   </td>
        <td> grammar             </td>
        <td> or                  </td>
        <td> whatever you prefer </td>
        <td> .                   </td>   
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

